# How can I hide mounted volumes when I still want USB volumes to appear on the desktop?

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, xfce, thunar

- Xubuntu 12.10
- XFCE 4.10 with Thunar 1.6.2

I have two greyed out mounted (or "mountable") volumes on my desktop:

[image]

If I right-click on them, I can *mount* them, implying they appear not be mounted yet. I don't understand really why they are greyed out as I can simply double-click them and then browse around. So they are mounted?

But on to my question: Neither the icon/volume named *Datenträger 58 GB* nor the icon/volume named *System-reserviert* appear in the fstab file, I checked that via GParted and sudo blkid. [Here is the output of sudo blkid](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5557762/). The thing is, I'd still would like to have the option *Unpluggable Devices* in the desktop setting (symbols tab) activated for USB-related stuff. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add them to your `/etc/fstab` and they will be hidden:

```
LABEL=fedora    /mnt/fedora ext4    noauto,rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,norelatime,user_xattr,acl   0   0
LABEL=FAT32     /mnt/FAT32  vfat    noauto,rw   0   0
LABEL=xp        /mnt/xp     ntfs    noauto,rw   0   0
LABEL=seven     /mnt/seven  ntfs    noauto,rw   0   0
```

- They need not be mounted at all, `noauto` acheives that.
- Do not mount them under `/home` if you use other file managers.
- They will still appear if you mount them under `/media`. Useful for eSata bay drives.
- This behavior is neither xfce nor thunar-specific, it affects all file-managers that employ gvfs.

Comment: Ok, so I added the two volumes via their UUID (instead of their label) and then took the option for the non-ext4 volums you listed. It looks like this now `UUID=4ECCB9F3CCB9D585 /mnt/Win7-normal noauto,rw   0   0`. I saved the file via `CTRL + S`, closed it and they disappeared. Great. Thanks!